# Getting error attempting to add multiple models to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I need to have 2 `models` in my View. But since we could only add 1 view, i took the following approach;

```
@model Tuple<My.Models.Mod1,My.Models.Mod2>

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item2.humanKind,Model.Item2.allHuman)


    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Item1.food)
```

But, what i end up getting is the following error;

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'My.Models.Mod2', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Tuple`2[My.Models.Mod1,My.Models.Mod2]'.
```

What is this, and how can i solve this?

UPDATE

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model2 = new Mod2 { allHuman = allHumans() };
            var model1 = new Mod1(); // JUST NOW I ADDED THIS, BUT IT DOESn't WORK
            return View(model1,model2);

        }
```

Comment: Post your controller code.

Comment: Your answer in this `@model Tuple<My.Models.Mod1, My.Models.Mod2>` line of code.

Comment: sorry @EricJ. I missunderstood, you are right.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları I have updated my post with the code

Comment: return View(new Tuple<My.Models.Mod1,My.Models.Mod2>(model1, model2);

Answer (score 1):

The view in question is being called from a controller action that only passes in a `My.Models.Mod2` rather than a `Tuple<My.Models.Mod1,My.Models.Mod2>`.

Double-check the specific controller action that calls this view.

**UPDATE**

Your controller code

```
return View(model1,model2);
```

should be

```
return View(new Tuple<My.Models.Mod1,My.Models.Mod2>(model1, model2>);
```

You are passing model1 and model2 as separate parameters rather than as a Tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one model per view.  You need to instantiate the Tuple as Ufuk suggested.

However I would suggest creating a new model that has the other models as a property.

Comment: I agree trying to hack multiple models in is not a good idea and will become messy to maintain, it might be better to look into using renderpartial/renderaction

Answer (score 1):

Build a view model that contains both:

```
Public class CompositeViewModel{
 Public Mod1 mod1 {get;set;}
Public Mod2 mod2 {get;set}
}
```

Then construct and pass CompositeViewModel to view. Set views to use CompositeViewModel as the model `@model CompositeViewModel`

Using a Tuple doesn't easily allow you to expand or change what you are doing.

It maybe even looks like you have one ViewModel that has data, and then some associated `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. If that is the case then name the ViewModel like CreateAnimalTypeViewModel which contains all the properties you need to create it, then have various select lists.

If you need to map from something to the ViewModel e.g. if you were doing an edit of an existing item you could use AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a tuple instance before sending it to the view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model2 = new Mod2 { allHuman = allHumans() };
    var model1 = new Mod1();
    return View(new Tuple<Mod1,Mod2>(model1,model2));
}
```